# How to mine multiwords from a given text in R?

Tags: r, string, text-mining

```
library(tm)
library(stringr)
txt <- "Netherland Belgium UK Sweden France Russia Government and People"
words <- c("land", "Sweden", "Government and People", "Government", "People")
pattern <- str_c(words,collapse ="|")
cntry <- str_extract_all(txt, pattern)
```

Although `land` is not found as a separate word in my text, the code takes from the last portion of `Netherland`. How I can enforce the code to strictly look for words included in `words` only? 
Output for the variable `cntry`:

```
 "land"  "Sweden"  "Government and People"
```

An output that I need for `cntry`:

```
 "Sweden"  "Government and People"
```

Comment: So you want `Government and People` and `Government` only if it's not `Government and People`?

Comment: Even if both are in `words`,  `txt` does not have `People`. In this case `Government and People` is fine for me. My problem is managing the issue of `land` and `Netherland`.

Comment: It's not a nice solution, but you could try: `pattern <- paste0("\\b", str_c(words,collapse ="|\\b"), "\\b")`

Comment: if it wasn't for multi-word strings e.g. `Government and People`, you could split on spaces (with `str_split`) and use `regmatches` with `regexec` on the resulting list to get what you need. If that can work for you, I can post an answer.

Comment: @Gautam Thank you for your comment. But the issue of multi-word is part of the problem in my set-up.

Comment: @Gadaa posted a work-around by separating expected multi-word values and desired single word output for terms like `land`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a not-so-elegant workaround, too long for comments, so posting as an answer. It appears that `land` is the problem string while others can be extracted using `str_extract_all` as posted in the comments.

In this answer I'm focusing on extracting `Netherland` given the pattern `land`. Another similar example would be extracting `Sweden` based on the pattern `den`.

Here's a function to achieve this using `regmatches` and `regexec`:

**FUNCTION**

```
return_partials <- function(txt, problem_patterns){
  ret_vec <- sapply(problem_patterns, function(z){
    list_output <- regmatches(x = txt, 
                    m = regexec(pattern = paste('[[:space:]]{0,1}?(.*', z, ')', sep = ''), 
                                text = txt))
    return(list_output[[1]][2])
  })
  return(unname(ret_vec))
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> return_partials(txt = txt, problem_patterns = c('land', 'den'))
[1] "Netherland" "Sweden"
```

You can combine it with the answer by Chris Ruehlemann:

```
words <- c("\\bland", "Sweden", "Government and People", "Government", "People")
pattern <- str_c(words,collapse = "|")
sol1 <- unlist(str_extract_all(txt, pattern))

sol2 <- return_partials(txt = txt, problem_patterns = c('land', 'den'))

> unique(c(sol1, sol2))
[1] "Sweden"                "Government and People" "Netherland"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the task is really only to prevent the extraction of `land` from `Netherlands`, that can achieved by adding the anchor `\\b` (for word boundary) to `land` in the vector `words`:

```
words <- c("\\bland", "Sweden", "Government and People", "Government", "People")
pattern <- str_c(words,collapse = "|")
str_extract_all(txt, pattern)
[[1]]
[1] "Sweden"                "Government and People"
```

Comment: Honestly, I want to bound all words in `words` for my practical work.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Is my solution not working for you? If you mean you want to wrap all items in `words`into `\\b` then @Martin Gal's solution `pattern <- paste0("\\b", str_c(words,collapse ="|\\b"), "\\b")` is an ideal and very clever solution